# UIView Perspective feature

Tags: ios, uiview, perspective

I've got a view and I would like to scale this view as like below image. How do we achieve this?

Thanks,
Mahesh[image]

Comment: Have you considered using affine transform?

Comment: No.. Please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: you can play with the `layer.sublayerTransform` and can set a matrix which defines the perspective for the actual view. that would not be a real 3D environment, but it is still good enough for making nice 2.5D effects in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotate your view's layer.  Something like this,

```
CALayer *layer = yourView.layer;
CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationTransform.m24 = 1.0 / -350;
rotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationTransform, 60*M_PI/180, 1.0, 0.0, -0.1);
[layer setTransform: rotationTransform];
```

Check out this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to understand CALayer's geometry and how it works.